# How to play ads without any video content with vast and video.js

Tags: reactjs, video, redux, graphql, video.js

I am a newbie in video.js
I wanted to display youtube like ads banner on the home screen.

```
var pluginSettings = {
            adTag: `https://myURL1.xml`,
            vpaidFlashLoaderPath:
                "https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid/blob/master/bin/VPAIDFlash.swf?raw=true",
        };

        videojs.plugin("ads-setup", function () {
            this.vastClient(pluginSettings);
        });
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, {
            autoplay: true,
            plugins: {"ads-setup": {}},
        });
```

This is the plugin I used.

My question is if i put my mp4 URL into src its giving me error

> Media not supported

If i put some static working URL its working, but i don't wanted to play any video which is given in source in video.js but i wanted to play video which is in the ads plugin.

```
<div data-vjs-player style={{width: "100%", height: "30%"}}>
                <video ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)}
                       preload='none'
                       id="my_video_1"
                       autoPlay
                       muted
                       controls
                       className="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                       width="100%" height="78%"
                       poster='http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg'
                >
                    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4"
                            type='application/x-shockwave-flash'/>
                </video>
            </div>
```

I don't wanted to play this source but only ads in my banner.

Comment: You cannot play SWF because it is a compiled application not a video file. Maybe the SWF code loads an MP4? I don't know what "home screen" means here but if you a Flash file (the SWF) and you want to display you can create an `<embed>` tag and put the SWF url there.

Comment: `<embed src="yourfile.swf" width="600" height="400"> </embed>`